# How to bind a port in a "host" network mode from a container run by a rootless dockerd?

Tags: docker

I want to publish a port to my host from a container. The container is running in ["host" network mode](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/) by [rootless dockerd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless).

My question is: how to publish a port to my host from this container (run in a "host" network mode using rootless dockerd)?

Should I run `dockerd-rootless.sh` script or even a raw `rootlesskit` with specific arguments to achieve this goal?

I have done the following steps:

1. Install a rootless dockerd on Ubuntu 20.04:

   ```
   $ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh
   $ export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
   $ export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/$UID/docker.sock
   ```
2. Run a rootless dockerd:

   ```
   $ dockerd-rootless.sh --experimental
   ...
   INFO[2020-06-03T16:53:51.690572434+02:00] API listen on /run/user/1000/docker.sock
   ```
3. Check a container in a non-host network mode (SUCCESS):

   ```
   $ docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 python python -m http.server 8080
   Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 (http://0.0.0.0:8080/) ...
   ```

   On other terminal:

   ```
   $ curl http://localhost:8080
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
   ...

   $ lsof -i :8080
   COMMAND      PID    USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
   rootlessk 116618 marcinr    9u  IPv6 2313409      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
   ```
4. Try to run in a "host" network mode (FAILURE):

   ```
   $ docker run --rm -it --network host python python -m http.server 8080
   Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 (http://0.0.0.0:8080/) ...
   ```

   On other terminal:

   ```
   $ curl http://localhost:8080
   curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

   $ lsof -i :8080
   <empty>
   ```

   I know I can run these commands using `nsenter`:

   ```
   $ nsenter -U -n -t $(cat /run/user/$UID/docker.pid) lsof -i :8080
   COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
   python  119656 root    3u  IPv4 2360676      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
   ```

   but I want to be able to use my web application in a web browser, not in a terminal only.

Answer (score 1):

--net=host is unsupported in Rootless as of Docker 19.03: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#networking-errors